STM32L0 SPI Mode always return MODF
I tried to setup a L0 using SPI to connect with LSM6DSR, all codes are generated using CubeMX (also the driver code for LSM6DSR with X-CUBE-MEMS1)
The weird thing is, when ever it tries to utilize SPI functions (Transmit, Receive, and Transmit/Receive), it will always return HAL_SPI_ERROR_MODF.  The SPI1 only have LSM6DSR connected, no other slaves, the only master is the L0.
The SPI is setup as below, generated by CubeMX but I think there shouldn't be a problem:
__weak HAL_StatusTypeDef MX_SPI1_Init(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef ret = HAL_OK;

  hspi->Instance = SPI1;
  hspi->Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi->Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi->Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi->Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi->Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi->Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi->Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi->Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi->Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi->Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi->Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(hspi) != HAL_OK)
  {
    ret = HAL_ERROR;
  }

  return ret;
}

The initalization code:
static int32_t IMU_Init(void){
  //Initialize LSM6DSR
  LSM6DSR_IO_t            io_ctx;
  uint8_t                 id;
  static LSM6DSR_Object_t lsm6dsr_obj_0;
  int32_t ret = BSP_ERROR_NONE;

    /* Configure the accelero driver */
  io_ctx.BusType     = LSM6DSR_SPI_4WIRES_BUS; /* SPI with CS */
  io_ctx.Address     = NULL; //Doesn't have an address for SPI
  io_ctx.Init        = BSP_SPI1_Init;
  io_ctx.DeInit      = BSP_SPI1_DeInit;
  io_ctx.ReadReg     = BSP_SPI1_SendRecv;
  io_ctx.WriteReg    = BSP_SPI1_SendRecv;
  io_ctx.GetTick     = BSP_GetTick;

  if (LSM6DSR_RegisterBusIO(&lsm6dsr_obj_0, &io_ctx) != LSM6DSR_OK)
  {
    ret = BSP_ERROR_UNKNOWN_COMPONENT;
  }
  else if (LSM6DSR_ReadID(&lsm6dsr_obj_0, &id) != LSM6DSR_OK) 
  {
    ret = BSP_ERROR_UNKNOWN_COMPONENT;
    Error_Handler();
  }
  else if (id != LSM6DSR_ID)
  {
    ret = BSP_ERROR_UNKNOWN_COMPONENT;
  }
  else
  {
    // Customization Part:
    // Enable Accelerometer only

    // Disable the Gyro
    if(LSM6DSR_GYRO_Disable(&lsm6dsr_obj_0) != LSM6DSR_OK)
    {
      ret = BSP_ERROR_COMPONENT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Setup Accelero
    if(LSM6DSR_ACC_SetOutputDataRate(&lsm6dsr_obj_0, 104.0f) != LSM6DSR_OK)
    {
      ret = BSP_ERROR_COMPONENT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(LSM6DSR_ACC_SetFullScale(&lsm6dsr_obj_0, LSM6DSR_ACC_SENSITIVITY_FS_4G) != LSM6DSR_OK)
    {
      ret = BSP_ERROR_COMPONENT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Setup Interrupt for wake up

    //Enable Accelero
    if(LSM6DSR_ACC_Enable(&lsm6dsr_obj_0) != LSM6DSR_OK)
    {
      ret = BSP_ERROR_COMPONENT_FAILURE;
    }

  }
  return ret;
}

I also noticed that when I set SPI_POLARITY_HIGH, the SCK line never idle-high. I tried to fix it with internal pull-up in GPIO init but then again, never fixes the MODF problem.

How exactly you connect the sensor to SPI interface? and how exactly you use the SPI? "SPI Master mode fault (MODF) –  Master mode fault occurs when the master device has its NSS pin pulled low (in NSS hardware mode) or SSI bit low (in NSS software mode), this automatically sets the MODF bit". You configure your SPI as SPI_NSS_SOFT which implies a 3-wire configuration, yet you have LSM6DSR_SPI_4WIRES_BUS; /* SPI with CS */...

@hcheung I'm using CS, MISO, MOSI and SCK. I mean, I had used this wiring method with SPI_NSS_SOFT many times before and it worked well. I was just manually doing chipselect.

@hcheung update: using hardware NSS doesn't work either. Still producing HAL_SPI_ERROR_MODF. I'm thinking about switching to I2C for now, since the due is closing in.

@hcheung another update: it looks like the BSP API generated by CubeMX has some kind of weird bug.... before I implement the BSP I2C, the original I2C using regular initialization works without issue, after the implementation, it will return error whenever I used I2C communications. ridiculous.
